# What tool to use to document HTTP request-response?

Tags: http, documentation

I am a developer at a start-up company. We've been developing an android application that uses HTTP protocol.

Currently we are using dropbox + MS word to interact with each other. As dropbox manages conflicted files by creating a new file, only one person per document is assigned to edit the documents.

I am in charge of documents that contain request-responses. Three developers use those documents daily.

Example of one our document is

```
1. Send person info
   A. Request (POST)
      I. Name: sendUserInfo, content: userNum:1, userName:Jee the Handsome ....
         a. userNae can be excluded.
   B. Reponse
      I. sendUserInfoSuccess or sendUserInfoFailed ...
```

As you may have guessed we found this very unproductive. If someone wanted to correct "userNae" to "userName", he had to tell me about it. Also, finding content in Word is sometimes hard. Either we use ctrl-F or go to the Index page(fortunately important parts are hypertexted in the index page).

Is there a good tool that is team-work friendly, and also easy to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Google Drive and Google Docs. It's quite the same setup but Google Docs provides multi user support.

If you wanna use some more professional tools have a look at [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/). But it takes some time to get familiar with them. Both are open source, which may be a factor.

Comment: I had no idea SVN worked with word documents. I think I will use tortoiseSVN.